# From xml to js SAPUI5 Custom List Item code NO ERROR IN THE CONSOLE

Tags: javascript, dynamic, rendering, sapui5, formatter

I'm trying to arrive at this custom design with Custom List Item -> [this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRJpe.png)
just that the icon content can be 3 types of icons with 3 types of colors.

I already did it with in the xml view

```
<List  items="{path: '/results'}" id="exemple">
                <CustomListItem>
                <FlexBox alignItems="Start"
                    justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                <items>

                <core:Icon size = "2rem" src="sap-icon://flag" /* I NEED 3 ICONS HERE*/  class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" />
                <VBox  class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" >
                <Label class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd" text="{BM}"  /> 
                <Label class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd" text="{BMS}"/>
                </VBox>
                </items>
                </FlexBox>
                </CustomListItem>
                </List>
```

but because I have to change the color and the icon in a dynamic way in base of some oData values, I want to do it in the controller so i can use the .onAfterRendering function and the formatter, in xml I don't know hot to specify him a formatter and manipulate it in the js controller.
I have a .onAfterRendering that changes my color in base of a oData value but I have to change even icon in base of that value.

So I tryed to write the code in js but i have the list with no data and no error in the console.

```
var view = that.getView();//get view                
                var oList = sap.ui.getCore().byId(view.createId('listjs')); 
                oList.setModel(oModel);
                var CustomListItemTemplate = new sap.m.CustomListItem();
                var FlexBox = new sap.m.FlexBox({
                        alignItems : "Start",
                        justifyContent: "SpaceBetween"
                        });
                FlexBox.addItem(
                        new sap.ui.core.Icon({
                                src : "sap-icon://status-error", //HERE I SHOULD HAVE A FORMATTER BECOUSE I NEED 3 ICONS "sap-icon://status-error", "sap-icon://status-SUCCESS" AND "sap-icon://SOMETHING ELSE"
                                size: "2rem"
                        }), 
                        new sap.m.VBox({

                        }),
                        new sap.m.Label({
                            text: "{BMS}"

                        }),
                        new sap.m.Label({
                            text: "{BM}"

                        })
                );
                /*oList.onAfterRendering = function() {
                if (sap.m.List.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
                    sap.m.List.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
                }
                var items = this.getItems();
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    var item = items[i];
                    var obj = item.getBindingContext().getObject();

                    switch (oData.results[0].BMS) {
                    case 'NOTGOOD':
                    {
                        item.$().find('.sapUiIcon').addClass('RED');

                    }
                    break;
                    case 'GOOD':
                    {
                        item.$().find('.sapUiIcon').addClass('GREEN');
                    }
                    break;
                    default:
                    {
                        item.$().find('.sapUiIcon').addClass('YELLOW');
                    }
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }*/
           oList.bindAggregation("items","/results" ,CustomListItemTemplate);
```

Comment: the id is different listjs from exemple becouse I tryed to re-create it so in my code there are 2 different list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not the use of formatters suffice?

```xml
<List  items="{path: '/results'}" id="exemple">
   <CustomListItem>
      <FlexBox alignItems="Start"
                    justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
         <items>
            <core:Icon size="2rem" class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom"
                       src="{path: 'BMS', formatter: '.formatIconSrc'}" 
                       color="{path: 'BMS', formatter: '.formatIconColor'}" />
            <VBox  class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" >
               <Label class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd" text="{BM}"  /> 
               <Label class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd" text="{BMS}"/>
            </VBox>
         </items>
      </FlexBox>
   </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

and in the controller:

```
formatIconSrc:function(bms){
   switch(bms){
      case 'NOTGOOD':
         return "sap-icon://status-error";
      case 'GOOD':
         return "sap-icon://status-success";
      default:
         return "sap-icon://somethingelse";
   }
},
formatIconColor:function(bms){
   switch(bms){
      case 'NOTGOOD':
         return "red"; //css colors supported
      case 'GOOD':
         return "green";
      default:
         return "yellow";
   }
},
```

Comment: An other possibility would be to add three `<Icon />` elements to the FlexBox - each with its own icon and css class. Then bind their visible property to the model using formatters in way that only one icon is visible at a time.

Comment: still nothing is displayed . :(

Comment: shouldn't I pass even the parameter of the formatter ? maybe something like formatter: '.formatIconColor'(bss) ? in the view

Comment: No, the formatter is feed with the values from the model described by the *path* binding property. Perhaps you have to enable complex binding mode by [specifying a minimum ui5 version](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/9feb96da02c2429bb1afcf6534d77c79.html) in your bootstrap tag: `data-sap-ui-compatVersion=edge`